# Контроллер в Laravel не получает объект класса

Tags: php, laravel

Есть Laravel 7

Есть модель:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Questionnary extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

Есть контроллер

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Questionnary;

class QuestionnaireController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Questionnary $questionnary) {
        return view('questionnaire.show', compact('questionnary'));
    }
}
```

Есть роут:

```
Route::get('/questionnaires/{questionnaire}', 'QuestionnaireController@show');
```

Есть запись в таблице:

```
|id|user_id|title|purpose|created_at|updated_at|
|1 |1      |title|p      |дата      |дата      |
```

В итоге в контроллер попадает пустой объект, при попытке обратиться к свойству id $questionnary->id, я получаю null. Что не так с инъекцией зависимостей, ведь по идем на основании ID 1 должен был быть построен класс, но почему он пустой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route::get('/questionnaires/{**questionnaire**}', 'QuestionnaireController@show');

Должно быть совпадение с названием класса questionnary

Route::get('/questionnaires/{**questionnary**}', 'QuestionnaireController@show');